# How to use Html color code in Java JPanel

Tags: java, html, swing, colors, jpanel

So, im trying to use a HTML color code `#F5FAE3` in a Java Gui.

I find this `Color aColor = Color.decode("#F5FAE3");`

But in my JPanel who is:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Color aColor = Color.decode("#F5FAE3");
    panel.setBackground(new Color(aColor));
    tabbedPane.addTab("Ropa Items", null, panel, null);
    panel.setLayout(null);
```

When i trying to call aColor i get this error from eclipse IDE:

```
The constructor Color (Color) is undefine
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after many atempts i see my problem, this method to use the HTML color is correct.

```
Color aColor = Color.decode("#F5FAE3");
```

You just have to call it in your Panel like: `panel.setBackground(aColor);`

Insted of: `panel.setBackground(new Color(aColor));` by the way the "new color" is create by eclipse for default.